# Смена фона с js

Tags: javascript, html

Написал код

```
function randColor() {
var red = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
var blue = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
var green = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
document.getElementById('boby').style.backgroundColor = "rgb+"("+txt+")"";

var txt = (+red+", "+blue+", "+green);
alert("rgb"+"("+txt+")");
}
```

чтобы менять  фон боди по клику.
Через alert видно что rgb передает правильный и если вместо того что выдает "rgb+"("+txt+")"" написать то что выдает alert то все заработает, но вот сам код при этом не работает.
Кто может подсказать почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все-таки лучше сначала присвоить переменной значение, а уж потом ее использовать.

```js
function randColor() {
  var red = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
  var blue = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
  var green = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);

  var txt = (+red + ", " + blue + ", " + green);
  //alert("rgb"+"("+txt+")");
  document.getElementById('boby').style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + txt + ")";
}

setInterval(randColor, 500);
```

```css
#boby {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="boby"></div>
<button onclick="randColor()">Click</button>
```

Comment: только заметил, но все ровно спасибо))